# Typescript checking for truthy value

Tags: typescript

I am fetching data in typescript and have the following types:

```
type GoodResponse = {
  status: 1;
  data: string;
}

type BadResponse = {
  status: 0;
  error: string;
}

type Response = GoodResponse | BadResponse
```

Now after fetching data, I try to check response like this:

```
const response = await fetchApi() // returns type Response
if (!response.status) return

const data = response.data
// Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Good Response | Bad Response.....
```

However if check for `response.status === 0` it works properly.

Comment: Seems to work fine: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4g9nAJgJQgZzHAdm6BeKAbwFgAoKKNYAQ2AFc0AuKARgG4yLFbrmqAnAJZYA5h1IBfMmVCQoAIWop0mHPiKdKNekygAGcRQj9+cfn2BDR4qaTIB6e6jRxBAI1xRBaKNSiI6MAAbQQBjWggAGko4KH4ILGoAWwhEL2AoYFiAWRBnVVwZcGhc-OxPAngkMrUoAB8FJRrCu1bECFCg6nioUPKM+IxyiGZSlWHxADM6LFDgQWwoSYQACgBKDVaKQUmoFYBCQYKIADoqWgYN+Pp+LGlyXv7-HigCI+GT7hpNRygABVMkH4oCgAHIvtRQf44OgoFg4BkIAAPbwZRayaCgqppZrQBqKHHjNQnEkksgSIA) I don't see the error you claim you have.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript should be able to know the type from your example alone what verssion of TS are you using?
Either way I think it would be best to use [User type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) in case the way to distinguish between responses ever changes:

```
const isBadResponse = (response: Response): response is BadResponse => !response.status;

const response = await fetchApi() // returns type Response
if (isBadResponse(response)) return;

// Now TS knows response is of type GoodResponse
const data = response.data;
```